# How do I repair items that I cannot equip?

Tags: diablo-ii

I'm playing as a summoning necromancer with most points in life. My hireling has pretty good weapons, but I can't seem to figure out how to repair his stuff, because my dexterity is *far* too low to be able to equip them myself. Is there any way to repair his gear without spending the next fifteen levels dropping all my points on dexterity?

Also, what will happen with his items once durability drops to zero? Will they just disappear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Diablo 2, to repair equipment all you need to do is talk to the camp blacksmith

- Act 1: Charsi
- Act 2: Fara
- Act 3: Hratli
- Act 4: Halbu
- Act 5: Larzuk

These NPCs give you the ability to repair any item currently in your inventory, even if it is not currently equipped.

[image]

The button I have identified with a green box is used to repair items individually. This can be used on any item in your inventory, equipped or unequipped.

The red box will repair all items you currently have equipped with one click (provided you have the gold).

However, when it comes to your hireling's gear, their equipment *does not degrade*. Therefore there is no need to repair it.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** some items may have an "Ethereal" attribute. This means that this item *cannot be repaired*. These items have a slightly see-through, or ethereal (hence the name) appearance.

Comment: While it is good to know that my hireling's gear won't lose durability, this answer is not entirely correct. When having my stuff repaired, I made sure to keep my hireling's pike (durability 20/25) in my equipment. It did not get repaired.

Comment: There are 2 options for repairing gear. One requires you to repair each item individually, and another repairs all items in your inventory at once. Shall update my answer to explain this.

Comment: There is another point in the question. Once a piece of equipment is broken (durability 0), it appears red. That piece of equipment is "unequipped" but will stay in the inventory slot. Your character will act as if that equipment is not currently equipped with that broken item.

Comment: To add to ChaseC's comment: there can be a domino effect of an item wearing out and unequipping.  If you have a weapon which gives +10 strength and it wears out, you lose the bonus, which may mean that your armor becomes unequipped as well.  And if your armor gave a +15 strength bonus that you needed for something else, you can end up with many items becoming unequipped and appearing red in the inventory.

Comment: @purple Yes, this is true, however that isn't exactly relevant to the question.